# element.style.backgroundImage = `url(${url})`; not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-audio

all. I meet a problem about how dynamically change a background image of a div. When I click the next button, I want to change the background image; however, the syntax 'disk.style.backgroundImage = "url(xxx)" does not working; how could i fix it? The below is corresponding codes, hope you guys could help me solve it.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div id="disk" class="player--info__left"></div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
        .player--info__left{
            position: absolute;
            width: 5.5rem;
            height: 5.5rem;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
            border-radius: 50%;
            padding: 2px;
            top: -1.5rem;
            left: -1.5rem;
            margin: 0 4px 2px 2px;
            background-image: url('/images/IMG_4328.JPG');
            background-size: cover;
            object-fit: cover;
            &:hover{
                transform: rotate(360deg);
                transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            }
            &::after{
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                border-radius: 50%;
                border: 3px solid rebeccapurple;
            }
        }
```

JS CODE , in this part I want to change the background image dynamically.

```
const songList = [
    {
        src: '/music/Gymnopédies.mp3',
        img: '/music-img/Gymnopédies.jpg',
        title: 'Gymnopédies',
        singer: 'Erik Satie',
    },
    {
        src: '/music/Old Town Road.mp3',
        img: '/music-img/Lil Nas X.png',
        title: 'Old Town Road',
        singer: 'Lil Nas X',
    },
    {
        src: '/music/Daddy.mp3',
        img: '/music-img/Daddy.png',
        title: 'Daddy',
        singer: 'Coldplay',
    },
];

let index = 0;
next.addEventListener('click', function () {
    ++index;
    if (index >= songList.length - 1) {
        index = 0;
    }
    // isPlaying = true;
    console.log(disk);
    console.log(diskp);
    disk.style.backgroundImage = `url(${songList[index].img})`;

    playSong();
    playerButton.click();
});
```

Comment: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905) Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** and a **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested? Make sure your background is on a _visible_ element with _positive height and width_.

Comment: Once I click the next button, the div does not change its background image and it keeps unchanged. And there is no error in the browser console, and all the images are stored in local machine. There is no HTTP response for the image.

Comment: Even locally, there is always a log entry in the Network tab. And what does the element Inspector reveal?

Comment: I don't know why, all other images have HTTP reseponse; but once I click the button, there is no HTTP response code for the image I want to change. And the original image keeps unchanged

Answer (score 1):

This snippet proves that there is no problem cycling through background images using a button click. Meaning your question is incomplete, the problem lies elsewhere.
We won't be able to answer your question unless you provide more details.

```js
const imageUrls = [
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/FullMoon2010.jpg/220px-FullMoon2010.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/97/The_Earth_seen_from_Apollo_17.jpg/220px-The_Earth_seen_from_Apollo_17.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/OSIRIS_Mars_true_color.jpg/220px-OSIRIS_Mars_true_color.jpg",
];

let index = 0;

function onButtonClick() {
  const disk = document.getElementById("disk");
  disk.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageUrls[index]})`;
  
  index++;
  if (index >= imageUrls.length)
    index = 0;
}
```

```css
#disk {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="onButtonClick()">Click me repeatedly to cycle through images</button>
<div id="disk" class="player--info__left"></div>
```

Comment: The problem for asker is that they didn't define `const disk = document.getElementById("disk");`

Comment: @VC.One I assumed that it wasn't included in the post, but that it had been defined somewhere else, since his comment said "And there is no error in the browser console". But you might be right! 