# How can i change background image through js code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have background image installed in css:

```
.indicator {
  grid-area: b;
  background-color: yellow;
  background-image: url(./maxresdefault.jpg);
}
```

and want to change it on event like that:

```
indicator.oncontextmenu = function() {
  indicator.style.background = '';
  alert('msg');
}
```

but have no clue which type of command is used to change the background image in css by js. how do i change it?

Comment: Easier would be to define another class with the seperate image, and then add/remove the class from the element in your event.  `element.classList.add('newclass');`  also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66286619/element-style-backgroundimage-urlurl-not-working

Comment: Using that process the background will actually be automatically replaced to that in onctextmenu on load. But if that is what you want use this **indicator.style.background = 'url(imageURL)';**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
indicator.addEventListener('contextmenu', () => {
    indicator.style.backgroundImage = "url('your_image.png')";
    alert('msg');
})
```